# How to use Relative paths in python with, "with open()" and windows cmd or powershell

Tags: python, relative-path

Here is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
date_time = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M")
with open("Keyboard\Program\log\_temp.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(f"Keyboard\Program\log\log-{date_time}.txt")
```

im trying to execude this in my windows cmd or ps but all i get is

> with open("Keyboard\Program\log_temp.txt", "w") as f:
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> 'Keyboard\Program\log\_temp.txt'

I also tried different solutions from stackoverlow but noething seemed to help for my

Comment: How is your folder structrure related to the code file?

Comment: my code file: E:\@CodingGameEngine\!Projects\PythonProjects\RandomProjects\Keyboard\Program\test.py
the file i try to write to: E:\@CodingGameEngine\!Projects\PythonProjects\RandomProjects\Keyboard\Program\log\_temp.txt

Comment: And what is your working folder when you run your code?

Comment: E:\@CodingGameEngine\!Projects\PythonProjects\RandomProjects\Keyboard\Program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your cwd is: `E:\@CodingGameEngine\!Projects\PythonProjects\RandomProjects\Keyboard\Program` then you only need to be relative to that:

```py
with open("log\_temp.txt", "w") as f:
```

Comment: Thanks its working havent even tryed just to shorten my string 

Comment: The usage of a path relative to current working directory in a Python script for referencing a file in same directory or a subdirectory of the directory containing the Python script is a bad design. The process starting `python.exe` to interpret a Python script defines the current working directory on calling on Windows the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) with the parameter `lpCurrentDirectory` being a null pointer or pointing to a directory path string.

Comment: A good design determines from within the Python script the absolute path of the currently interpreted Python script file and concatenates the script file path with the name of the file to read/write without or with additional path parts. The Stack Overflow search [[python\] _\_file_\_](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+__file__) finds lots of questions and answers using the [_\_file_\_](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) property to get the absolute path of the directory containing the interpreted Python script file.

Answer (score 0):

Programs, in general, don't know or care *where their executable lives*. When you run them, you are starting them from some *working directory*, and all relative pathnames are interpreted from there.

When you start a program from the command line, it's easy to see what your current working directory is (Run `pwd` in PowerShell or bash, or `cd` in CMD). When you start a program by double-clicking an icon, however, Windows changes the current working directory to the one containing the program. That's why it's easy to get confused and think relative paths are always relative to the folder containing the program.

If you're writing something to be run from the command-line, you might want to write it to use absolute paths instead of assuming the user will be where you think they are. You can always get the path from an environment variable if you want the user to be able to configure it.